# Cannot subscript a value of type '[Any]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am retrieving data from firestore and so far everything is successful.  This is the result in my console.

```
[{
    Name = Tuna;
    Price = "$3.6"; }, {
    Name = Snapper;
    Price = "$25.60"; }]
```

I want to store Name and Price into variables so that I can display them in my table view. As shown in the code bellow when i set nameOfItem to the Data2, i get an error that states, "Cannot subscript a value of type '[Any]' with an index of type 'String'". I was wondering if someone can help me fix this!

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                    itemCollectionRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                        if let err = error {
                            debugPrint("Error fetching docs: \(err)")

                        }else {
                            guard let snap = snapshot else {return}
                            for document in snap.documents {
                                let data2 = document.data()["Items"]! as? Array ?? []
                                print(data2)
                                let RandomVariable = data2[0]
                                print(RandomVariable)

                                let nameOfItem = data2["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                                let priceOfItem = data2["Price"] as? String ?? ""

                                //let priceOfItem = data2["Price"] as? String ?? ""
                                //print(nameOfItem, priceOfItem)

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What's the type of your object `snapshot `? Is that a dictionary or array of objects?

Comment: `[Any]` is an `Array<Any>`. It's not a dictionary that you can subscript with a string.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see for yourself there is no such thing as an "Items" element in your console output instead as the error message says you have an array so change your code inside the for loop to

```
let data = document.data() as? [Any] ?? []
for item in data  {
    if let dictionary = item as? [String: String] {
        let nameOfItem = dictionary["Name"] ?? ""
        let priceOfItem = dictionary["Price"] ?? ""
        //...
    }
}
```